# Reduce Polynomial Over Real Numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I was given the question $x^8 + 16$ and told to reduce it as much as able over the real numbers.

Here is what I tried

$x^8 + 16$

$(x^4+4)^2-8x^4$

$(x^4+4-2^{3/2}x^2)(x^4+4+2^{3/2}x^2)$

I can not figure where to go from here, I have also tried using complex conjugates and multiplying them to get it factored, which leads me to getting

$x^2-2^{3/2}x\cos{(\pi/8)}+2$ as a factor, which when I try to put in a calculator to expand further yields me the wrong result.

Can anyone explain where I am going wrong and how I can reduce it further?

Comment: first try  $t^8  + 1.$   All are 16th roots of $1$  What are the fourth roots of one, then the eighth roots of one, then the sixteenth roots of one?   Straightforward if you use the formulas for $\cos \frac{\theta}{2}$ and   $\sin \frac{\theta}{2}.$   Anyway, rootss come in conjugate pairs $a$ and $\bar{a}$  and the quadratic that takes care of that pair is $t^2 - t(a + \bar{a}) + 1 $

Comment: @WillJagy I've tried using the formulas for cos and sin but I wasn't able to factor it properly, I only got to $x^2+2-2^{7/4}x$ which according to the answers is wrong